OpenID Connect using .NET 8
I am struggling to get OpenID Connect (using ping federate) to work on .NET 8. Can someone post a full example of how it works? I keep getting remote login failure. I have an API controller which I decorated with [Authorize]. Any help appreciated. I am migrating from .NET 4x to .NET 8 (still a little new to all the syntax).
I want to authorize and authenticate user using API - there is no client login page involved. I have authority, clientid and secret I keep running into remote failure message state is empty or null
I have tried everything on the net, even tried jwtbearer. I have added UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization after UseRouting. I just want this on controller to use [Authorize] attribute and I want to be able to read the user and get claim information which is all null or 0
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/auth")]
public class AuthController : Controller
{

[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(){

    _logger.LogInformation("i am here");
     var claims = p?.Claims;
         string name = "";
         foreach(var c in claims)
            if(c.type.EndsWith("nameidentifier"))
                name = c.Value;
}
}

in program.cs i have this
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
  options.DefaultScheme =  CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}
 .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
 {
    options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost;
    options.Authority = "https://my-idp-website.com";
    options.ClientId = "17990c36-59f3-4d345cd57D45";
    options.ClientSecret = "some secret key";        
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
    options.CallbackPath = "/api/Auth";    
    options.SaveTokens = true;        
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
   
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("phone");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");



 options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
      OnTokenValidated = context =>{
         var p = context.Principal;
         var claims = p?.Claims;
         string name = "";
         foreach(var c in claims)
            if(c.type.EndsWith("nameidentifier"))
                name = c.Value;
            
       
        return Task.FromResult(0);
      },
      OnRemoteFailure = context =>
      {
         context.Response.Redirect("/");
         context.HandleResponse();
         return Task.FromResult(0);
      }
   };
 });

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


Go see here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC - it also has tons of other samples

thanks for the links. I think i have been here before but none of this helps. I dont even seem to be hitting ping federate

If you want to fix the issue, it's better to create a brand new project which can reproduce the issue for us. It's hard to analyze the issue without any code. And please hide your sensitive information, tks~

I have added Code in my orgiginal post, are you able to asssist?

I thought when i decorate with [Authorize] attribute on controller it will go to program.cs and do the authentication and it will come back to that controller get method again where i can read all the claims and process the rest....but i never see i am here logging and neither do i get any claims but do see in on token validated.

For anyone who struggled with this like me....all i had to do was include ClaimTypes.Tole in tokenvalidation params and then things started lookingup. Thanks to all who commented earlier.
